# discord bot send metadata and gifs and this 5 times

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, giphy-api

I tried to make a Bot that sends gifs from giphy. I made it with python and Giphy Core Client for Python. So if someone type

> /OwO Giphy Spongebob

It sends a random spongebob or some other memes. The problem is that it send the metadata and gif 5 times. I hope someone can help me that the bot send only the gif and only 1 time.
I have the Python Version 3.8.

> ```
>         if message.content.startswith("/OwO Giphy") or message.content.startswith("/OwO giphy"):
>             try:
>                 q = message.content
>                 tag = q.replace('/OwO Giphy ', "")
>                 api_response = api_instance.gifs_random_get(api_key, tag=tag, rating='pg')
>                 await message.channel.send(api_response)
>
>             except ApiException as e:
>                 print("ERROR! Exception from Api try")
> ```

[image]

Comment: The link is being posted multiple times in one message. It's not being sent 5 times

Comment: Instead of sending the response, you should be sending one of the keys inside the JSON. Also, you should be using `discord.ext.commands` if you plan on making a Discord bot

Answer (score 0):

FINAL SOLUTION: I didn't add 'embed_url'

```
if message.content.startswith("/OwO Giphy"): 
api_instance = giphy_client.DefaultApi() 
api_key = 'TOKEN' 
q = message.content tag = q.replace('/OwO Giphy ', "") 
api_response = api_instance.gifs_search_get(api_key, q=tag, rating='pg13') 
gif_list = list(api_response.data) 
giff = random.choice(gif_list) 
await message.channel.send(giff.embed_url)
```